# Keys not being returned in reduce function

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchdb, couchdb-nano

Using Nano to query a Couch view in NodeJS, to count the occurrences of tags in all documents. If I choose reduce in Fauxton on the view, it correctly displays with each tag name as the key, and the count. However, from my Node app, I just get 'Null' as the key, and a total of *all* tags.

The tag name (rather than the _id) is stored in each document. This is my map function (using the _count reduce function):

```
function (doc, meta) {
  if(doc.tags) {
    for(var i in doc.tags) {
      emit(doc.tags[i],1);
    }
  }
}
```

This is my (Nano) code in Node:

```
app.get('/listtags', function(req, res) {
    couch.view('objects', 'tags-count', {reduce: true}, function(err, body) {
        console.log(body);
    });
});
```

And it returns:

```
{ rows: [ { key: null, value: 8 } ] }
```

**EDIT**
Adding example docs:

Tag:

```
{
"_id": "...",
"_rev": "1-...",
"type": "tag",
"name": "petrol"
}
```

Doc containing tags:

```
{
"_id": "...",
"_rev": "3-...",
"type": "car",
"title": "Audi",
"desc": "description here",
"tags": [
  "petrol",
  "aircon",
  "leather seats"
]
}
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of the a document entry?

Comment: added example docs

Comment: Try with {reduce:true,group_level:true}. If it works, I will post this as the answer

Comment: That didn't, but I tried without '_level' and it did:  {reduce:true,group:true}

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have to specify either the `group_level` option or the `group=true` option.

eg :

```
app.get('/listtags', function(req, res) {
    couch.view('objects', 'tags-count', {reduce: true, group: true}, function(err, body) {
        console.log(body);
    });
});
```